# Displaying results as hyperlinks to an additional query?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking for a way to display MySQL results as hyperlinks that will perform another query when clicked.

Say I have a 2 tables in my database linked by `ALTER TABLE topics ADD FOREIGN KEY(topic_cat) REFERENCES categories(cat_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

categories:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cat_id          | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cat_name        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| cat_description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

topics:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| topic_id      | int(8)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| topic_subject | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| topic_date    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| topic_cat     | int(8)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| topic_by      | int(8)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I also have a PHP search form that queries the table "categories":

```
$var = @$_GET['search'] ;
  $trimmed = trim($var);

$query = "select * from categories where cat_name like \"%$trimmed%\"  
  order by cat_name";
```

I want to be able to display the results of the above query as hyperlinks and when clicked, I want to display results that are linked to "cat_name" by "topic_cat" and "cat_id".  I can't seem to find an example of this anywhere online.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I'm still a noob at the whole php/mysql thing.

Comment: Google the term... and replace the MySQL book that you're using with a superior one.

Answer (score 0):

When you output results, do
`print ("<a href='show_category_topics.php?id=".$row["cat_id"]."'>".$row["cat_name"]."</a>");`

On a new page (`show_category_topics.php`) run the query
`$query = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_cat ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"])."'";` and print results.

You can also use ajax calls to php pages.